# Difference between Emacs Starter Kit, Prelude and Graphene

Tags: emacs

[Emacs Starter Kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit), [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude), [Graphene](https://github.com/rdallasgray/graphene) are various customization packages for [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

How are they different? What are their emphasis and strengths in comparison? Can they all be installed together?

Comment: My advice would be to forget about the starter kits and install only individual packages that you believe would be useful -- try them out and then delete them if you don't like them.  The starter kits that I have tried had lots of stuff that I never used, and then I had trouble trying to figure out why certain default settings didn't work as expected -- i.e., because the starter kit was overriding them.

Comment: @lawlist: why don't you turn it into an answer?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028055/where-i-can-find-the-most-popular-emacs-settings

Comment: Being a Emacs novice too, I disagree with @lawlist. It was only after using Spacemacs for a few months that I was able to see what Emacs is capable of in practice, that gave me the confidence that I would replace my IDE with emacs. Being a novice and having to choose every single package is overwhelming.